# Storing application size/position preferences?

Tags: java, swing

Getting back into java programming. Last time I used it generics were just being introduced, so it's been awhile.

Has anything been changed or added to make it easier to store window information when you close an application?  Say a user resizes the window, adjusts a split pane, or just places the window elsewhere on the desktop I'd like the application to reopen with the last configuration.  Or am I still stuck storing all those values individually into a file myself?

Comment: Which framework are you talking about ? Swing? JavaFX ?

Comment: You can attach listeners to all events you have mentioned and react accordingly.

Comment: I'm using Swing. Listeners is a decent idea, just hoped there was a simpler method than all that extra work.

Comment: 7 years ago and Java has added a lot so I didn't know if that answer was still relevant.